# Cant make dialogue work when player is near NPC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I' trying to get my player to have a dialogue with a NPC on collision enter but nothing happens, here is the code:

The player has Rigidbody2D and Capsule Collider2D what should i do?

Im running unity 2021.3.11 and I tried multiple tutorials and fixes but nothing worked.

If anyone has another dialogue method please write it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialoguePanel;
    public Text dialogueText;
    public string[] dialogue;
    private int index;
    public GameObject contButton;
    public float wordSpeed;
    public bool playerIsClose;
    IEnumerator Typing()
    {

        foreach(char letter in dialogue[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(wordSpeed);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerIsClose)
        {
            if (dialoguePanel.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                zeroText();
            }
            else
            {
                dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
                StartCoroutine(Typing());
            }
        }
        if(dialogueText.text == dialogue[index])
        {
            contButton.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void NextLine()
    {
        contButton.SetActive(false);
        if(index < dialogue.Length - 1)
        {
            index++;
            dialogueText.text = "";
            StartCoroutine(Typing());
        }
        else
        {
            zeroText();
        }
    }

    public void zeroText()
    {

        dialogueText.text = "";
        index = 0;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnTirggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            playerIsClose = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTirggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            playerIsClose = false;
            zeroText();
        }
    }
  


}
```

Comment: Put a print statement in the ontriggerenter and exit function to determine if they are even being called or if the if statement inside of them is being called.

Comment: Wow now i notice is just a typo i wrote Tirgger